# Computer can't find bs4 & beautifulsoup4, though it was installed

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm currently working through Al Steigart's *Automate the Boring stuff with Python*. In chapter 12, We deal with pip installations of beautifulsoup4.

In CMD, `"C:\Users\timwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts"`

I installed:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I also installed,

```
pip install bs4
```

I received the message that it was installed afterwards. However, after looking in my file directory for Scripts, I could not find beautifulsoup4 or bs4 present.

I also tried importing bs4 & beautifulsoup 4 from the Python IDLE, and received this message:

```
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

>>> import beautifulsoop4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    import beautifulsoop4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoop4'

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Comment: do you have multiple python versions installed on this machine?

Comment: @con Yep. I believe I have two versions installed.